# c# Отправка файла по ftp асинхронно. Этот вариант не слишком избыточен в смысле асинхронности?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, ftp, async-await

Сразу скажу что это рабочий вариант:

```
public async static void SendFileToFtp(string ftpAddress, string ftpUser, string ftpPassword, FileInfo file)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}{1}", ftpAddress,file.Name));
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file.FullName);
    byte[] sBuffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    await fs.ReadAsync(sBuffer, 0, sBuffer.Length);
    fs.Close();

    Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
    await stream.WriteAsync(sBuffer, 0, sBuffer.Length);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Суть вопроса в слудующем, не слишком ли много await в этом случае. await request конечно должен быть, но вот имеет смысл считывать и записывать файл с await? (await fs.ReadAsync,  await stream.WriteAsync).

Как выяснилось это не избыточно, а нормально и разве что можно обернуть потоки в using. Так же рабочий вариант будет такой но проблема с безопасностью выполнения FtpWebRequest останется.

```
public async static void SendFileToFtp(string ftpAddress, string ftpUser, string ftpPassword, FileInfo file)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}{1}", ftpAddress, file.Name));
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open)) 
    {
        byte[] sBuffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        await fs.ReadAsync(sBuffer, 0, sBuffer.Length);
        fs.Close();
        using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(sBuffer, 0, sBuffer.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Решается это непростым путём, вот ссылка с MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: все три операции потенциально долгие, так что лично я избыточности не вижу. Но я бы использовал `using` в работе с потоками, т.к. любая из операций с потоками и сам запрос могут кинуть исключение и до `close` дело не дойдет, а потоки очень желательно диспозить независимо от результата операции в целом.

Comment: ок, потоки обернем. Сам FtpWebRequest обернуть нельзя, у него нет IDisposable. Получился такой код для потоков :  
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open)) {
        byte[] sBuffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        await fs.ReadAsync(sBuffer, 0, sBuffer.Length);
        fs.Close();
        using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(sBuffer, 0, sBuffer.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }

Comment: У вас в последнем примере лишний 'fs.Close();'

Comment: Спасибо уберу.  А stream.Close() не лишним будет , по аналогии или в данном случае мы как раз освобождаем удаленный ресурс?

Comment: @Pannacottik конечно же будет. Для потоков Close и Dispose - это одно и то же

Comment: Если вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос - пожалуйста, напишите его в форме ответа, а не в форме дополнения к вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, избыточности нет. Следует только обернуть потоки в конструкцию `using`.

В общем пусть будет так. Безопасность FtpWebRequest оставим за кадром.

```
public async static void SendFileToFtp(string ftpAddress, string ftpUser, string ftpPassword, FileInfo file)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}{1}", ftpAddress, file.Name));
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open)) 
    {
        byte[] sBuffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        await fs.ReadAsync(sBuffer, 0, sBuffer.Length);
        using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(sBuffer, 0, sBuffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Можно упросить до такого вот решения что бы писать в другой поток(сразу на сервер) без предварительной буферизации.

```
public async static void SendFileToFtp(string ftpAddress, string ftpUser, string ftpPassword, FileInfo file)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}{1}", ftpAddress, file.Name));
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096, true)) {
        using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            await fs.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А не лучше ли использовать `fs.CopyToAsync(stream)`? Файл-то может большим быть...

Comment: Я собственно не знаю что из этого будет. Что делает CopyToAsync? типа сразу без копирования в буфер ?

Comment: Читает все из одного потока и записывает в другой.

Comment: А файл да, можеть быть большим и плюс такие же операции могут быть запущены в другой сессии.

Comment: Спасибо, записал в решение дополнительно. Нужно отметить получилось лаконично.

Comment: Насчет последнего апдейта, может получиться так, и у меня так получилось, что файл еще нужен параллельно другой задаче (Task) что бы куда-то отправить. В данном случае это второй ftp, и yandex диск. Так вот т.к. файл занят без предварительной буферизации валится эксепшн, естественно.  Я вот думаю, файл действительно может быть большим, получается что потребуется создавать временную копию файла ?

Comment: Нет никакого запрета открывать один и тот же файл несколько раз. Разбирайтесь с эксепшеном...

Comment: `FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite` - вот это точно лишнее. Достаточно `FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite`, а лучше все-таки `FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read`

Comment: Кстати, у FileInfo есть метод [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/d3wke8tz(v=vs.110).aspx)...